# how can i set custom bullet image of li tag?

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to set custom image as a bullet. when i am using background or background-image tag it is work but not align properly with list category. And when i am using list-style-image it is not displaying the image as a bullet.

Problem :

**Css**

[image]

**Firebug**

[image]

Image is also displaying in firebug when i move my mouse over on it

**Wrong final output**

[image]

Solution :

***Correct Output what i want***

[image]

Comment: Try to add this `css` property into `.vMenu li`and check it out `list-style-type: none; width:19px; height:19px;`

Comment: And set `background:url(...);` instead of `list-style-image:url(...)`

Comment: I normally add it as a background image on the `li`, positioned `left` `center` with `x`px of padding left. Can't say I've used `list-style-image` before

Comment: @Adam i had also us a background image but when i am using padding from top in li at that time image does not set properly with li. i had also use line height property as well ass scroll but it does not working properly.

Comment: `background: url('/image/arrow.png') no-repeat left center;` On the `li`. Try setting the height of the li to the height of your arrow (19px) and use the line-height to center the text.

Comment: @AnandMehta : You need to customize only the `height` and `width` parent `<div></div>` part. Then set the image also like this way.. `background:url('...') no-repeat top left;`

Comment: @Ranjith thanks Ranjith for the precious help... sorry for the late reply to your comment... :)

Comment: @AnandMehta : It's ok. welcome. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one method that I tend to lean on. Add a `before` to the `li`, size it as required and add a background image to it.

Then just sprinkle some flexbox on to stop the text wrapping underneath the bullet.

I made a quick [jsfiddle to demonstrate it](http://jsfiddle.net/kvpw3s4z/)

```
li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;

    line-height: 30px;

    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    display: block;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    vertical-align: middle;

    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1168/1168671.png') no-repeat left center;
    background-size: contain;

    content: '';
}
```

Comment: thanks adam your answer is working exactly as what i want. thanks for doing such fruitful effort for give me solution of problem from your busy schedule.... thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Put and li Class**

and put **class ' background link to the image** as the bullet