# I wanna set same image for all ul list items in html

Tags: html, styles, html-lists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY0cr.jpg)I was trying to set the same image for all ul or ol items in HTML but couldn't do it. help me pls!

ol { font-size:25pt; background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:32px; } ul { font-size:20pt; background-image:url('flash.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; list-style: none; padding-left:32px; }

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. JS

- HTML
- CSS
- JS

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: You can achieve this by using `li:before` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15924533/14038646

Answer (score 2):

You should first look at this :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image

And then try `list-style-image` property